# Any sources for UV light exposure on land for various geographies?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, weather, climate

We are looking for daily amounts of UV light falling onto the earth. We have been able to find weather reports through [Google BigQuery from the U.S. NOAA's NCDC](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/bigquery-public-data:noaa_gsod.gsod2016) but they don't appear to track sunshine hours.

Does anyone know of a source for solar environmental data?

Comment: Are you interested in incident UV A/B/C or Sunshine Hours? Are you interested in point locations or global averages? This is a fairly comprehensive topic in the environmental sciences.

Comment: Point locations or small regions. Incident UV A/B/C is ideal. Sunshine hours is non-ideal - but would be a reasonable surrogate - particularly if intensity or brightness is part of that measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running list of UV/UVI/Air Quality/AQI data sources:
[Ultraviolet Index issued by NWS](http://forecast.weather.gov/product.php?site=CRH&product=UVI&issuedby=CAC)
[World Ozone and Ultraviolet Radiation Data Centre (WOUDC)](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/docucomp/page?xml=NOAA/NOSA/iso/xml/GLOBAL-WOUDC.xml&view=getDataView&header=none)
[Solar Ultraviolet Spectral Irradiance](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/stp/solar/solaruv.html)
[Solar Data Services](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/stp/solar/solardataservices.html)
[Solar UV Index](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/stratosphere/uv_index/uv_current_map.shtml)
[Stratosphere: UV Index](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/stratosphere/uv_index/)
[Global Fields of UV Index Forecasts](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/stratosphere/uv_index/uv_global.shtml)
[NECP FTP](ftp://ftpprd.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/hourly/prod)
[USDA/Colorado State Univ UV-B Monitoring and Research Program](http://www.nws.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/nwsexit.pl?url=nadp.nrel.colostate.edu/UVB/)
[NOAA SURFRAD - SURFRAD (Surface Radiation) Network](http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/grad/surfrad/)
[SURFRAD FTP](ftp://aftp.cmdl.noaa.gov/data/radiation/surfrad/)
[NOAA FTP Radiation Directory](ftp://aftp.cmdl.noaa.gov/data/radiation/)
[World Ozone and Ultraviolet Radiation Data Centre (WOUDC)](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/docucomp/page?xml=NOAA/NOSA/iso/xml/GLOBAL-WOUDC.xml&view=getDataView&header=none)
[UV Alert Forecast Map](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/stratosphere/uv_index/uv_alert.shtml)
[Ultraviolet Index Information - NWS](http://www.nws.noaa.gov/om/heat/uv.shtml)
[Daily UV Forecast - Map of Danger Areas](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/stratosphere/uv_index/uv_current_map.shtml)
[Daily UV Forecast - Text List of UV Levels by City](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/stratosphere/uv_index/bulletin.txt)
[Daily UV Forecast - Monthly Means and Maximums](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/stratosphere/uv_index/uv_meanmax.shtml)
[Daily UV Forecast - Annual Time Series of UV Index Forecasts](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/stratosphere/uv_index/uv_annual.shtml)
[Daily UV Forecast - Past UV Bulletins](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/stratosphere/uv_index/Bulletin/)
[Daily UV Forecast - NWS Local Forecasts](http://www.weather.gov)
[Current UV Index Forecast](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/stratosphere/uv_index/uv_current.shtml)
[Archive of UV Index Bulletins](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/stratosphere/uv_index/uv_archive.shtml)
[Monthly Means and Maximums](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/stratosphere/uv_index/uv_meanmax.shtml)
[Annual Time Series of UV Index Forecasts](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/stratosphere/uv_index/uv_annual.shtml)
[UV Radiation and UV Index Information](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/stratosphere/uv_index/uv_information.shtml)
[Sun Safety](https://www.epa.gov/sunsafety)
[SunWise at NEEF](http://neefusa.org/sunwise)
[SunWise History at EPA](https://www.epa.gov/sunsafety/history-sunwise-program-epa)
[UV Index Scale - EPA](https://www.epa.gov/sunsafety/uv-index-scale-1)
[Ultraviolet Radiation and the INTERSUN Programme](http://www.who.int/uv/en/)
[UV Index Reporting Sites](http://www.who.int/uv/resources/link/indexlinks/en/)
[Global Solar UV Index](http://www.who.int/uv/publications/globalindex/en/)
[Typical Values for UV Irradiation - SoDa](http://www.soda-pro.com/web-services/typical-years/typical-uv)
[Search Results for "UV Index" - NASA Earthdaa Search](https://search.earthdata.nasa.gov/search?q=UV+Index&ok=UV+Index)
[UV Index Forecast and Archives](http://www.temis.nl/uvradiation/)
[World: UVAwareness.com, Ireland](http://www.uvawareness.com/)
[Europe: Integration and exploitation of networked Solar radiation Databases for environment monitoring](http://www.soda-is.com/index.html)
[Europe: The Met Office (UK)](http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/weather/europe/europe_uv.html)
[Mediterranean Basin: Environmental Forecast and Information Service (French/English/Spanish/Italian)](http://www.enviport.com/index_en.html)
[Australia: Bureau of Meteorology](http://www.bom.gov.au/weather/uv/)
[Argentina: Servicio Meteorologic Nacional (Spanish)](http://www.meteonet.com.ar/)
[Canada: Meteorological Service of Canada (English/French)](http://www.ec.gc.ca/uv/default.asp?lang=En&n=396B9A58-1)
[Finnish national public information service (in Finnish language)](http://www.fmi.fi/uvi)
[Finnish national public information (in Swedish) service](http://www.fmi.fi/vader/varningar_6.html)
[France: Securité Solaire (French)](http://www.securite-solaire.org/)
[Germany: Bundesamt für Strahlenschutz (German)](http://www.bfs.de/en/uv/uv2/uv_messnetz/uvi)
[Germany:  Deutscher Wetterdienst (German)](http://www.uv-index.de/)
[Greece: Laboratory of Atmospheric Physics (Greek)](http://lap.physics.auth.gr/uvindex/)
[Hong Kong: Hong Kong Observatory](http://www.weather.gov.hk/wxinfo/uvindex/english/euvtoday.htm)
[Italy: Stazione Metereologica del La.M.M.A. (Italian/English)](http://www.lamma.rete.toscana.it/previ/ita/stazlam.htm)
[Luxembourg: Meteorological Station of the Lycée Classique de Diekirch (English)](http://meteo.lcd.lu/today_01.html)
[Netherlands: Royal Netherlands Meteorological Institute (UV Index)](http://www.temis.nl/uvradiation/UVindex.html)
[New Zealand: Lauder National Institute of Water and Atmospheric Research (NIWA)](http://www.niwa.co.nz/our-services/online-services/uv-and-ozone)
[Poland: Instytut Meteorologii i Gospodarki Wodnej (Polish/English)](http://www.imgw.pl/)
[Spain: National Meteorological Institute (Spanish)](http://www.aemet.es/es/eltiempo/observacion/radiacion/ultravioleta)
[Switzerland: Bundesamt für Gesundheit (German/French)](http://www.uv-index.ch/)
[United States: The Weather Channel](http://www.weather.com/maps/activity/health/skin/index_large.html)
[United States: NOAA/ EPA Ultraviolet Index](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/stratosphere/uv_index/uv_current.shtml)
[Sun Safety - Cancer Control PLANET](https://cancercontrolplanet.cancer.gov/sun_safety.html)
[Erythemal Exposure (Erythemal UV Exposure, Erythemal UV Daily Dose,  UV Daily Dose)](http://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/data-holdings/PIP/erythemal_uv_irradiance.shtml)
[Ozone Data Centers](http://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/ozone/additional/links/ozone-data-centers)
[World Ozone and Ultraviolet Radiation Data Centre](http://woudc.org/)
[UV Related Links - NOAA](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/stratosphere/uv_index/uv_links.shtml)
[OAA Antarctic UV Monitoring Network](http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/grad/antuv/)
[UV Index: Annual Time Series](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/stratosphere/uv_index/uv_annual.shtml)
[UV Index EPA Envirofacts API](https://www.epa.gov/enviro/web-services#uvindex)
[UV Net Data Archive](https://archive.epa.gov/uvnet/web/html/access.html)
[UV Index - UV-B Monitoring and Research Program](http://nadp.nrel.colostate.edu/UVB/da_queryUvIndex.jsf)
[UV Index - UV-B Monitoring and Research Program](http://nadp.nrel.colostate.edu/UVB/uvb-dataAccess.jsf)
[Air Quality Index KML](https://files.airnowtech.org/airnow/today/airnow.kml)
[County Level UV Exposure Data for the Continental United States](https://gis.cancer.gov/tools/uv-exposure/)